# 52 cards are equally given to 4 players Find probability that one of them has 3 spades out of remaining 5.

Tags: probability

52 cards are equally given to 4 players $A,B,C,D$.
Together, $A$ and $B$ have a total of 8 spades among them,
and we have to find probability that $C$ has 3 spades out if remaining 5.

In this question, the sample space reduces to 44 cards after we eliminate 8 spades from the cards, so now we have 5 spades left from which 3 will be given to $C$, and the remaining 10 cards can be chosen from the remaining 39 cards so I get the answer as
$$ \frac{\binom{5}{3}\binom{39}{10}}{\binom{44}{13}},$$
is this approach correct?

Comment: Do you mean exactly three or at least three?  (if the latter, the answer is $\frac 12$ as either $C$ or $D$, but not both, must have at least three).

Comment: Aside from the issue of "exactly" vs "at least", your method is flawed.  There aren't $44$ cards left to choose from, there are only $26$ of which $5$ are Spades and $21$ are Other.  Also, having chosen your three Spades, you must then choose the remaining $10$ cards from the Other (else you count the same combinations multiple times).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are only 26 cards left in the deck. 5 are spades, 21 are not. We use the $\frac{Number- of -favorable -outcomes}{Number- of- possible- outcomes}$ formula. Thus we get $\frac{{5 \choose 3}{21 \choose 10}}{{26 \choose 13}}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Question**: In the card game bridge, the 52 cards are dealt out equally to 4 players - called East, West, North and South. If North and South have total of 8 spades among them, what is the probability that East has 3 of the remaining 5 spades?

**My Approach**: My answer to the above question was:

East can get 3 spades out of remaining 5 spades in $\binom{5}{3}$ ways.

All possible outcomes are $\binom{5}{0}+\binom{5}{1}+\binom{5}{2}+\binom{5}{3}+\binom{5}{4}+\binom{5}{5}$. i.e., East gets no spades, or 1 spade or... and so on.

Therefore, the desired probability = $\frac{\binom{5}{3}}{\binom{5}{0}+\binom{5}{1}+\binom{5}{2}+\binom{5}{3}+\binom{5}{4}+\binom{5}{5}}= \frac{10}{32} = .3125$

However, as per Sheldon Ross' book, the answer is 0.339. I understand how he arrived at the solution. But, I do not see what is wrong in the above approach. Why don't the answers match?

Answer (score 0):

It is given that A and B have a total of 8 spades among 26 cards.
∴ In the remaining 26 cards, there are exactly 5 spades.
These 26 cards are distributed equally among C and D [13 each]

P(C has 3 of 5 spades) =  $\frac{{5 \choose 3}{21 \choose 10}}{{26 \choose 13}}$
= 0.339